# PayPal REST API with PHP results ERROR

Tags: php, rest, paypal

Im using PayPal REST API with PHP, I have created a rest app in sandbox and everything as in documentation.

but it returns error

```
Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token.
```

not sure where Im going wrong on this, tried many other sample codes using rest api but same error everywhere.

can some one help me on this?

code is here

```
define('CLIENT_ID', 'MY CLIENT ID'); //your PayPal client ID
define('CLIENT_SECRET', 'MY SECRET'); //PayPal Secret
define('RETURN_URL', 'http://domain.com/order_process.php'); //return URL where PayPal redirects user
define('CANCEL_URL', 'http://domain.com/payment_cancel.html'); //cancel URL
define('PP_CURRENCY', 'USD'); //Currency code
define('PP_CONFIG_PATH', ''); //PayPal config path (sdk_config.ini)

include_once "vendor/autoload.php"; //include PayPal SDK
include_once "functions.inc.php"; //our PayPal functions

    $item_name = 'Test Product'; //get item code
    $item_code = 'sku123'; //get item code
    $item_price = '10'; //get item price
    $item_qty = '1'; //get quantity
    /* 
    Note: DO NOT rely on item_price you get from products page, in production mode get only "item code" 
    from the products page and then fetch its actual price from Database.
    Example :
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT item_name, item_price FROM products WHERE item_code= '$item_code'");
    while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
        $item_name = $row->item_name;
        $item_price = item_price ;
    }  
    */

    //set array of items you are selling, single or multiple
    $items = array(
        array('name'=> $item_name, 'quantity'=> $item_qty, 'price'=> $item_price, 'sku'=> $item_code, 'currency'=>PP_CURRENCY)
    );


    //calculate total amount of all quantity. 
    $total_amount = ($item_qty * $item_price);

    try{ // try a payment request
        //if payment method is paypal
        $result = create_paypal_payment($total_amount, PP_CURRENCY, '', $items, RETURN_URL, CANCEL_URL);

        //if payment method was PayPal, we need to redirect user to PayPal approval URL
        if($result->state == "created" && $result->payer->payment_method == "paypal"){
            $_SESSION["payment_id"] = $result->id; //set payment id for later use, we need this to execute payment
            header("location: ". $result->links[1]->href); //after success redirect user to approval URL 
            exit();
        }

    }catch(PPConnectionException $ex) {
        echo parseApiError($ex->getData());
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: You can post your actual source code

Comment: `HTTP Error 401` means `Unauthorized` so check your credentials.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola AFAIK only credentials we have to setup are REST APP client ID and client secret correct? or there are any others to set up?

Comment: Make sure you are using correct sandbox credentials.

Comment: Check out this for further info: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-payments-error-handling/

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola fake credentials?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82298/discussion-between-coderows-and-indrasinh-bihola).